# android market: upgrade or unpublish?

Tags: android, maps, google-play, api-key

I have an app on the market. However, I noticed that I made a bug, which was that I did not sign the maps api key with the key md5 key that i signed the published app. Therefore, should I upgrade the app, or unpublish and republish it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload an upgrade. Dont unpublish your app. I think if you unpublish your app and publish again, your current users wont be able to upgrade their current installation.

Comment: correct, and he also won't be able to upload the app with the same package name if I remember correctly. Which means he needs to refactor it and change the package name. Just upgrade it.